# VBA Using a cell value in an .xlsm workbook to name a .xlsx workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Copying and pasting cell values from one workbook to another identical (locked) workbook, last step is to name the workbook a specific cell vale from the first workbook.  Everything works to the naming part:

```
    Windows("load from sheet.xlsm").Activate
Range("AD25:AE25").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Windows("load to sheet.xlsx").Activate
Range("AD25:AE25").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Dim fileName As String
fileName = "D:\CVE\nitro round 5\all service new\load from sheet\" & Range("AO49").Text & ".xlsm"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileName:=fileName, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveWindow.Close
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the workbook also to get the Range.  It will default to Activeworkbook.

`Windows("load from sheet.xlsm").activesheet.range("AO49").value`

something like that.